# JQuery Table Show Head, When Hover Show Body, When Click Show Body. Need for MANY tables

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have this code working but would like to have it so as I add more tables I don't have to keep adding all these sections and formatting.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/QtMK2/120/
I want the click and toggle functions to act EXACTLY how they do in the example.

I just want to be able to have it so that as I add more tables, I don't have to have keep adding all the functions for each new table.

So is there any way to make this so it uses the (this) variable to only act on that table?

-JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
var clicked1 = false; //Used tp keep tr from closing
var clicked2 = false; //Used to Keep tr from closing

//Table1 Hover
$('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards1 th.AwardsDeMolayHead1') .hover(function(){
if(!clicked1) {                
 $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards1 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody1').toggle();         
}});
 //Table2 Hover 
$('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards2 th.AwardsDeMolayHead2') .hover(function(){         
if(!clicked2) {         
  $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards2 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody2').toggle();         
}});

 //Table1 Click    
 $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards1 th.AwardsDeMolayHead1').click(function(){         
        if(!clicked1) {return clicked1 = true;  
                      $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards1 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody1').show(); }
          if(clicked1) {return clicked1 = false;  
                      $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards1 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody1').hide(); }
});

  //Table2 Click 
  $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards2 th.AwardsDeMolayHead2').click(function(){         
        if(!clicked2) {return clicked2 = true;  
                      $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards2 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody2').show(); }
          if(clicked2) {return clicked2 = false;  
                      $('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards2 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody2').hide(); }
 });       


//LOAD CLOSED

$('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards1 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody1')  .hide();

$('.ActiveDeMolayTableAwards2 tr.AwardsDeMolayBody2')  .hide();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I'm short on time and doing this from my head. But instead of specifying every single table and th one by one, can't you just reference them all, and then in the function refer to $(this)? For example, make selectors like this:

```
$('table[class^="ActiveDeMolayTableAwards"] th[class^="AwardsDeMolayHead"]')
```

That says to select all tables with a class that starts with 'ActiveDeMolayTableAwards' for example.

The other thing to do is to use the .live() function as opposed to the document.ready() as live() will react to dynamically added tables and include them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make all table elements same class. and manipulate within each scope. here I used a "stayOn" class to track the "clicking state"

http://jsfiddle.net/Et6XX/